# Removing source ports from a SPAN session on a cisco nexus switch

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-commands, mirror, cisco-nexus

So, I have built a tool that allows users to configure `SPAN` sessions on a Cisco switch. I'm currently trying to get the application to work for the `Nexus` series but there is one command I'm not sure of.

When you are removing a port from a `SPAN` session, you would use the following example command `no monitor session 1 interface fastethernet 0/2`, but I'm unsure if that command works on the Nexus series. I have looked through the config guides, and all they show is how to add ports, but they don't show how to remove ports from a SPAN session. Unfortunately, I don't have access to that type of switch yet, and I would like to know the command before I test my application on the switch.

Does anyone know if this the right command for removing ports from a session, or is there different command used on the `Nexus` series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cisco is pretty consistent with using the `no` in front of a command to remove or disable the command. Cisco provides many documents, such as [Cisco Nexus 5000 Series NX-OS Software Configuration Guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5000/sw/configuration/guide/cli/CLIConfigurationGuide/Span.html) which detail how to configure SPAN, including removing it:

[image]

You add a source port to a SPAN session with:

```
switch(config-monitor)# source interface <type> <slot> / <port> [ rx | tx | both ]
```

You remove a source port from a SPAN session with:

```
switch(config-monitor)# no source interface <type> <slot> / <port>
```

Comment: perfect thanks, thats what i actually have in my code but i was unsure better safe than sorry